# sed to replace a line with containing wild card character

Tags: sed

Need help with this one, I am trying to replace a line containing wild card character

Orginal File :

```
command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_aix_cpu.pl $ARG1$ $ARG2$
```

It needs to be replaced with

```
command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_aix_cpu.pl -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

Comment: What have you tried?  How did it go?  Generally, asking a question without showing any attempt goes down quite badly.

Comment: hi rob   i tried these , it didn't work for me sed 's/command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_aix_cpu.pl $ARG1$ $ARG2$
/command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_aix_cpu.pl -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$/' filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can make it:

```
sed 's/\([$A-Z0-9]*\) \([$A-Z0-9]*\)$/-w \1 -c \2/' file
```

It gets the two last blocks of words (possible characters: `A-Z0-9$`) and prints them back with the format `-w BLOCK1 -c BLOCK2`.

The output is as follows:

```
command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_aix_cpu.pl -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

Answer (score 0):

hope I understood you right, check the following `awk` and `sed` one-liners:

```
kent$  cat f
command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_aix_cpu.pl $ARG1$ $ARG2$

kent$  awk '{$2="-w "$2;$3="-c "$3}7' f
command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_aix_cpu.pl -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$

kent$  sed -r 's/ \S+ / -w&-c /' f     
command[check_cpu]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_aix_cpu.pl -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

Comment: on last sed, you assume there is no other "space" in the line (in command or path/file or in $ARG value ). Very well done